# What was it that made the compiler change from a dynamic call in the first example to a static call in the second?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, overriding

This is a continuation of my [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23738748/2548699). Note that the code below makes a **virtual call** at `p->f(1.0)` printing `Derived::f(double)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace::std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f(double);
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

void Base::f(double) { cout << "Base::f(double)\n"; }

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void f(std::complex<double>);
    void f(double);
};

void Derived::f(std::complex<double>) { cout << "Derived::f(complex)\n"; }
void Derived::f(double) { cout << "Derived::f(double)\n"; }

int main()
{
    Derived* p = new Derived;
    p->f(1.0);
    delete p;
}
```

If I just eliminate the member function `void f(double);` in `Derived`, the code makes a static call to `Derived::f(std::complex<double>)`.

What was it that made the compiler change from a dynamic call in the first example to a static call in the second? I would appreciate some quote from the Standard.

**Edit:**

The answers to the question to which this was considered a dup don't cite the Standard, as I asked above. Thanks.

Comment: Did you expect something else to happen?

Comment: Why does everyone always write `new` and `delete` for those examples?! No need...

Comment: @KerrekSB maybe this explains: http://stackoverflow.com/a/334752/5987

Comment: My answer to your original question answers this one too. :) Edit: But not with a quote from the standard.

Comment: Asking for a reference to the standard does *not* make your question different. If you really want that reference add a bounty to the other questions stating it as the reason for the bounty, or just comment an answer and ask for it.

Answer (score 3):

> What was it that made the compiler change from a dynamic call in the first example to a static call in the second?

The lookup rules. Without the declaration of `f(double)` in derived (and lacking a using-declaration) the `f(complex<double>)` **hides** `f(double)` in the base. When the compiler does lookup for `p->f(1.0)` inside `Derived`, finds an overload and given a single option uses it. It never moves up to `Base` to check whether there are different overloads.

Comment: It's worth stressing that this has nothing to do with virtual polymorphism at all. It's a simple property of class inheritance.

Comment: My understanding was that a virtual function declaration in the Base would always have priority in cases like this. Could you provide a specific quote from the Standard supporting what you said above? The other answer from which this was considered a dup doesn't cite the Standard.

Comment: How about 10.2 of the C++11 draft standard (emphasis mine): "2. The following steps define the result of name lookup for a member name f in a class scope C... 4. If C contains a declaration of the name f, the declaration set contains every declaration of f declared in
C that satisfies the requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs... If the resulting declaration set is not empty, the subobject set contains C itself, *and calculation is complete.* 5. Otherwise [look in the base class]."